# C# How to Get list of Ids from Parent-Child list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of tasks containing parent-child relation. The relations keep getting changed. As the list structure is flat, i need to keep each task sorted, by DisplayOrder column.

### Fields:

```
TaskID - Title   -    ParentID  -  DisplayOrder
1        A Task       Null      -     1
2        B Task       Null            3
3        C - A        1               2
4        D - B        2               4
```

What I can imagine that after any relation is changed, I get all the tasks Ids in a way that each child ID is under its own Parent-ID and then update the DisplayOrder in of those IDs in their current sequence.

But I am not sure how this is possible in c#. Please advise in this regard.

Comment: Please give some example data and what you want to achieve. It is hard to grasp right now.

Comment: This is the look of table. Task keeps added and their parent-ID may also be changed, so to display a flat list on screen, I added the DisplayOrder column. Now if the relation is changed I need also to reOrder the sort column

Comment: Ok, now example result you are expecting. Suppose I change relation, pinning task C to A. What should be the result?

Comment: "C-A" is child of "A Task" . I can make it child of "B Task". now the order should be 1,2,4,3 respectively. But the main point is that I need all TaskId each child must be under its parent id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a tree structure, so this calls for recursion.

If I understand you correctly, you want to enumerate the tasks in the following way (pseudo code, obviously):

```
foreach(rootTask in all-tasks-having-no-parent)
{
    yield return rootTask;
    foreach(childTask in rootTask's-direct-children)
    {
        do-the-same-with-childTask-and-its-children-as-I'm-doing-with-rootTask;
    }
}
```

So let's implement the recursive method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Traverse a hierachy of items depths-first.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The item source.</param>
    /// <param name="childrenGetter">Function to get the direct children of an item.</param>
    /// <returns>The items in <paramref name="source"/>, each recursively followed by it's descendants.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DepthFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> childrenGetter)
    {
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
            foreach (var descendant in childrenGetter(item).DepthFirst(childrenGetter))
                yield return descendant;
        }
    }
}
```

All we need now is to know the root tasks as well as how to get the child tasks for a given task. Both is most easily and efficiently done with a `Lookup`, which essentially is a dictionary with the value type being an IEnumerable.

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    new Task { Id = 1, Title = "A", ParentId = null },
    new Task { Id = 2, Title = "B", ParentId = null },
    new Task { Id = 3, Title = "C", ParentId = 1 },
    new Task { Id = 4, Title = "D", ParentId = 2 },
};
var childrenByParentId = tasks.ToLookup(t => t.ParentId);
```

Now you can enumerate the tasks in the desired order and assign the `DisplayOrder`:

```
var order = 0;
foreach (var task in childrenByParentId[null].DepthFirst(parent => childrenByParentId[parent.Id]))
    task.DisplayOrder = ++order;
```

Comment: Is there a way that the DisplayOrder of the newly moved items is placed at last of its parent

Comment: The code I provided (thanks for accepting it) does not specifically order the children of a task among themselves, i.e. it keeps the order they originally have. If you have a sort criterion (like by Id or by Title), you can therefore presort the whole input, like: `var childrenByParentId = tasks.OrderBy(t => t.Title).ToLookup(t => t.ParentId);`. However I can't see how to detect in the input "newly moved items", unless you enhance it by that information.

Comment: Yes I was also expecting that some more information would be required for newly moved items as neither the above OrderBy method nor the giving some high DisplayOrder to new items worked. Since this kind of experience is new for me, therefore I relied upon best practiced code.

Comment: Great answer. Great way of using .ToLookup method.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like is a tree structure.
You should mount something like this:

```
      root 
        |
  ----------------
  |              |
A Task        B Task 
  |              |
C - A         D - B
```

After that you should make a depth first search to create 
 the DisplayOrder.
Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

EDIT: The portuguese version has a nice image that helps: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_profundidade#/media/File:Depthfirst.png

Then you will get this:

```
    root (0)
        |
  ----------------
  |              |
A Task (1)    B Task (3)
  |              |
C - A  (2)    D - B  (4)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes in theory this is what I want to achieve, but I need c# linq method to extract flat list of TaskID in a fashion that all children Ids are under their Parent Ids

Comment: I don't think you can do all of this in one linq method. Don't know if is you requirement, but imagine that you have a F (TaskId 5) that depends on D - B (TaskId 4). Will be hard to accomplish that.